# How to Create tilted actionbar (toolbar) in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shapes

I want to create ActionBar as below. How can we create? How should I create it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/su4ra7z7lyirfto/actionbar.png?dl=0
(image link)

Comment: Use a custom drawable for your `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that in the fast way do this,

1. Remove the action bar. "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);" after setCOntentView.
2. in your XML put a LinearLayout at top pretending to be the action bar.

Comment: How to draw this strange shape using xml?